# Python subprocess call is not running in order

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, subprocess

I am attempting to write a python file that calls a bash script. I have the following code

```
Print ("hello before subprocess call")
subprocess.call(['/builds/adummyscript.sh'], shell=True)
Print ("hello after subprocess call")
```

The dummy script is just a bash script with the following code

```
echo "hello from the inside of the subprocess call"
```

the output of my code is then

```
hello from the inside of the subprocess call
hello before subprocess call
hello after subprocess call
```

My question is why is the subprocess being run before the print statement and how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is running after your print statement, python just doesn't flush its stdout buffer before the subprocess is called. use `flush=True` to flush python stdout or use unbuffered python when calling your script.

```py
print("hello before subprocess call",flush=True)
```

Comment: ended up going with sys.stdout.flush() because flush = true is not an option for subprocess.call